# Best practice to implement SSO authentication for internal applications e.g. airflow dashboard, apache spark notebook, etc

Tags: security, authentication, web-applications, single-sign-on, intranet

I want to implement SSO for internally used applications including

- Apache Spark dashboard
- Jupyter notebook
- Apache Airflow dashboard
- Hadoop dashboard
- etc

I like to use subdomains for each application but secure each application via single sign on (SSO) either using Google Accounts or Auth0.

How would I do this? Would I have one application behind each domain that checks for the authentication token and then redirects to the respective application?

What is the best practice here?